# How to track other application's event

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net, winforms

My client has a previously developed windows application which they don't have the source code. They need a dash board in the application. This application has a option to add and call third party application, so I developed a dash board screen application with all the data they needed and add it in their application. But they wanted to see the dash board in side the main screen (just like MDI from and child form). I am thinking I can place my new application in such way that it will look like a child form but I need to track the minimize, maximized and close event of the main application so can change my application accordingly. Is it possible?

Comment: `so I developed a dash board screen application with all the data they needed and add it in their application.`, how did you add it if you dont have the source code? Are you just overlaying this? Also, there are many details left out currently for us to help you. Please update your post with what you have tried and where you are stuck so we can better assist you.

Comment: HI, Thanks for your reply. Yes I should elaborate more and yes I am trying to overlying it only.

Comment: In previous app user can add new crystal report or new program by clicking on a new button and browsing the desired .rpt or .exe file. Then a new icon is added to the menu items for that report or program. Basically both apps are different, only calling the new exe from the old app. But I want to make it in a way so user can feel that they are using a single app. when they will open my app from the main app my app will appear like a child form. only thing I need to manage is to minimize, restore & close my app when main app is minimized, restore & close.

Answer (score -1):

For the last part of your question if you want the new app intercepts when the first one being maximized or minimized, you can use global hooks.you can try this link:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/802412/Global-Interceptable-Program-and-System-Hooks-in-N

Comment: Hi, posting links to external sites is discouraged. Simply because, in the future the page could be taken down and other users searching for an answer will no longer have one. It's better to copy the relevant information and attribute it to the linked page. Thanks

Comment: Accept my excuse for not being aware of that.